# What is use of method addJar() in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, jar, classpath

In a Spark job, I don't know how to import and use the jars that are shared by method `SparkContext.addJar()`. It seems that this method is able to move jars into some place that are accessible by other nodes in the cluster, but I do not know how to import them.
This is an example:

```scala
package utils;
    
public class addNumber {
  public int addOne(int i) {
    return i + 1;
  }

  public int addTwo(int i) {
    return i + 2;
  }
}
```

I create a class called `addNumber` and make it into a jar file `utils.jar`.

Then I create a Spark job with the code below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    
object TestDependencies {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    sc.addJar("/path/to//utils.jar")
        
    val data = 1 to 100 toList
    val rdd = sc.makeRDD(data)
        
    val rdd_1 = rdd.map(x => {
      val handler = new utils.addNumber
      handler.addOne(x)
    })
        
    rdd_1.collect().foreach { x => print(x + "||") }
  }
}
```

The error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: utils/addNumber` was raised after submission of the job through `spark-submit`.

I know that `addJar()` does not guarantee jars are included into classpath of the Spark job. If I want to use the jar files, I have to move all of dependencies to the same path in each node of cluster. But if I can move and include all of the jars, what is the use of method `addJar()`?

I am wondering if there is a way of using jars imported by method `addJar()`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try set the path of jar with prefix "local"? From the documentation:

```java
public void addJar(String path)
```

> Adds a JAR dependency for all tasks to be executed on this
> SparkContext in the future. The path passed can be either a local
> file, a file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported filesystems), an HTTP,
> HTTPS or FTP URI, or local:/path for a file on every worker node.

You can try with `setJars` as well:

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster('local[*]')
             .setAppName('tmp')
             .setJars(Array('/path1/one.jar', '/path2/two.jar'))
    
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

and take a look [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sparkcontext.html#__a_id_jars_a_distribute_jars_to_workers), see `spark.jars` option

and set `--jars` param in `spark-submit`:

```bash
--jars /path/1.jar,/path/2.jar
```

or edit `conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /path/1.jar:/fullpath/2.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /path/1.jar:/fullpath/2.jar
```

Comment: hi @mariusz051 , I tried to add local: as prefix but still have the same problem. From log, spark did copy my jar and add it to the classloader, but this class still cannot be found in executor.

Comment: addJar doesn't add it into the classpath of the master JVM -- it assumes that those classes are already there, and it just adds a JAR to send to worker nodes

Comment: @NayanSharma I have edited my answer including yours tips

Comment: @mariusz051 After some research I found that `addJar()` does not add jar files into driver's classpath, it distribute jars (if they can be found in driver node) to worker nodes and add them into executors' classpath. Because I run the spark in local mode, driver's class path is used in spark job. That is the reason that classes cannot be found in spark job.

Comment: @Frankie ok, so now everything is clear how it works, great :)