# Spark and Elastic causing jackson overlap

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, jackson, classpath

We recently upgraded spark to 2.2.0 in our application and this brings in Jackson 2.6.5 jars in the runtime.

But we have other services that need Jackson 2.8.6(due to Elastic 5.5.0) the service has a manifest which refers to Jackson 2.8.6 from the application's lib folder.

So there are two versions of Jackson jars loaded in the runtime and spark is picking a wrong one (2.8.6 from lib folder instead of  2.6.5 from its own jars folder)

On windows the version picked is the right one although both versions are still loaded in the runtime.

But it fails on Linux.

How do we resolve this?

Comment: how are you submitting spark job is it through spark-submit ? if so plz mention the full command details

Answer (score 1):

You can add jars to the classpath [programatically using `addjar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957696/what-is-use-of-method-addjar-in-spark), inside file spark-defaults.conf or with spark-submit flags.

Also, We have 2 properties from [runtime-environment docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) here to mitigate conflicts

```
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst
```

> default false (Experimental) Whether to give user-added jars
>   precedence over Spark's own jars when loading classes in the driver.
>   This feature can be used to mitigate conflicts between Spark's
>   dependencies and user dependencies. 
>   ***Note*** : It is currently an experimental
>   feature. This is used in cluster mode only.

```
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst
```

> default  false    (Experimental) Same functionality as
>   `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst`, but applied to executor instances.

Properties set directly on the `SparkConf` take highest precedence, then flags passed to `spark-submit` or `spark-shell`, then options in the `spark-defaults.conf` file